# F# how to call this function 5 times?

Tags: f#

How do you call this **function f** 5 or times so that the returned value of **function f** will be the input value of **f function** next time you call it?

```
let test x = x + 1
let test2 (f : int -> int) = 
    f 1    
test2 test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use composition for that: *f o f*.  The operator in F# is *>>*

```
let test x = x + 1
let test2 (f : int -> int) = 
    let g = [1..5]
                |> List.map (fun _ -> f)
                |> List.reduce (>>)
    g 1

test2 test // 6
```

In the above code the g function is the equivalent to

```
let g = f >> f >> f >> f >> f
```

composing the function *f* 5 times, that is taking is output as input in the next function.

The map operation creates 5 copies of the function:  [f ;f ; f; f; f]
and the reduce combines the first with the next, and then the result with the next until there's only one result:

```
 f >> f  // [f; f; f]
 (f >> f ) >> f // [f; f]
 (f >> f >> f ) >> f // [ f ]
 (f >> f >> f >> f ) >> f
```

Comment: Explain your code please (every line), starting from let g =

Comment: @TheManthis I added more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to the problem, using recursion so you can optionally control the number of times you repeat `f`.

```
let repeater repeat f init =
    match repeat with
    | 0 -> init
    | _ -> repeater (repeat - 1) f (f init)
```

To use it you would call it like so:

```
let test x = x + 1

let res1 = repeater 5 test 1 // Gives 6
```

The advantage to this is you can repeat any number of times. You can also bake in either the first parameter or first two parameters:

```
let repeatFiveTimes = repeater 5
let res2 = repeatFiveTimes test 1

let repeatTestFiveTimes = repeater 5 test
let res3 = repeatTestFiveTimes 1
```

and get a reusable function for our specific use case.